# How to re-color polygon in KML file when styles use same id

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to re-color polygons from a KML.
I fetch it from a server, then use:

*getFeatures().getChildNodes().items(n).getComputedStyle()*

to manipulate the style, which works fine if there is no *styleUrl* element.

Some of the KMLs I want to load use the same styleUrl for all the polygons in the file, so changing one changes them all.

How can I add a unique *styleUrl* to each polygon, or better yet, change the style of an individual polygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waht about getFeatures().getChildNodes().items(n).setStyleSelector?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to override the styleUrl element, even when I tried to set it to null